# Update WampServer PHP 5.3.13 To PHP 5.4.45 Doesn't Work

Tags: php, wampserver

I'm trying to upgrade the PHP on my WampServer installation (Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.3.13, MySQL 5.5.24) from PHP v5.3.13 to v5.4.45.  **I only want to update PHP, not any of the other WampServer components.**  I've confirmed that my installed WampServer was compiled with the Microsoft VC9 compiler and that PHP 5.4.45 is also compiled with the same Microsoft VC9 compiler.  I've used the instructions given at this link in the *HOW TO MANUALLY INSTALL A NEW RELEASE OF PHP INTO THE WAMP ENVIRONMENT* section (a little more than halfway down in the article) to install PHP 5.4.45:

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,60567,page=2

When I change my PHP version from 5.3.13 to 5.4.45 (using the WampServer menu that's displayed when I click on the WampServer Task Bar icon) the color of the WampServer icon changes from green (when PHP 5.3.13 is selected) to orange (when PHP 5.4.45 is selected).  Does anyone have an easy-to-understand set of instructions for upgrading just the PHP component of WampServer?  I'm really sketchy in my knowledge about how to upgrade individual WampServer components, so I am looking for something basic that covers every step in 'beginner detail.'  I don't want to upgrade the entire WampServer environment because I'm using the current WampServer installation as my Website development platform and that would affect my already-developed Websites.

Thanks In Advance For Your Help -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that my installed WampServer is 64-bit and that the only available PHP 5.4.x download available from PHP.net is 32-bit.  **Both the compiler versions and the bit count must match in order to upgrade PHP successfully in a WampServer environment.  This is because WampServer runs PHP as a "subroutine" of Apache.**  The compiler versions used to create my 64-bit Apache 2.2.22 and the 32-bit PHP 5.4.45 both match (VC9). However, the PHP 5.4.45 download available on PHP.net is 32-bit (there is no 64-bit option).   The 32-bit version won't work with my 64-bit Wampserver (specifically the 64-bit Apache 2.2.22) and that's why my upgrade PHP failed.

Answer (score 1):

download [PHP 5.4.45](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.4.45-src.zip)

download other version http://windows.php.net/download#php-5.5

copy to:

> c:\wamp\php\

Comment: I'm not sure what you are suggesting here, Mass log.  A little more explanation, please?